Using Cloud Run with Next.js for handling redirects
Currently, I’m having an issue when deploying my application using Next.js 14.2.4. This is the function that redirects upon making a request. Everything works locally and when deploying on Vercel. However, when deploying on Google Cloud Run, I’m experiencing problems with the functionality of the application. Some sections completely stop appearing and working after being redirected.
route.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET (request: Request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url)
  const vacancyId = searchParams.get('vacancyId')

  if (!vacancyId) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'vacancyId is required' }, { status: 400 })
  }

  // Get the original host from X-Forwarded-Host header or use a default value
  const originalHost = request.headers.get('x-forwarded-host') || 'default.host'
  const baseUrl = `https://${originalHost}`

  // Log the baseUrl and redirect URL for debugging
  console.log('Base URL:', baseUrl)

  const redirectUrl = new URL('/form/personal-info', baseUrl)
  redirectUrl.searchParams.append('vacancyId', vacancyId)

  // Log the redirect URL for debugging
  console.log('Redirecting to:', redirectUrl.toString())

  try {
    return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl.toString())
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Redirect failed:', error)
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to handle redirect' }, { status: 500 })
  }
}

I tried deploying the application on Vercel, and it works correctly. However, when deploying it on Google Cloud Run, it doesn't work properly.

Not a Next.js developer but familiar with Cloud Run. I think there's no x-forwarded-host header in Cloud Run requests and so your code will default to default.host which won't resolve. You may want to try host header to get the service's address.

Now I'm getting redirected properly, but the application isn't loading correctly afterward.

"isn't loading correctly" isn't helpful. Please don't ask updated questions in comments. Your question as posted appears to be addressed. You may want to consider asking another question with the updated issue.
